# Sequential compute value through columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Given the values like below:

```
    Name     init     month1     month2     month3     cal1     cal2     cal3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Andy      2.2       1.3       2.5         1.5
    Brian     1.8       2.1       1.2         0.8
    Cindy     1.5       3.3       3.1         2.2
```

I want to use one SQL Statement to fill in the "cal" columns with the formula below: 
cal1 = init - month1
cal2 = init - month1 - month2
cal3 = init - month1 - month2 - month3
...
...
cal24 = init - month1 - month2 ... month24

So the result will be like this:

```
    Name     init     month1     month2     month3     cal1     cal2     cal3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Andy      2.2       1.3       2.5         1.5       0.9     -1.6     -3.1
    Brian     1.8       2.1       1.2         0.8      -0.3     -1.5     -2.3
    Cindy     1.5       3.3       3.1         2.2      -1.8     -4.9     -7.1
```

I use a most stupid way to achieve the goal:

```sql
SELECT a.*
    , a.init - month1 as cal1
    , a.init - month1 - month2 as cal2
    , a.init - month1 - month2 - month3 as cal3
FROM temp_table a
```

Is there any more elegant way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Your current query is what I would use and I consider it to already be an optimal approach.

Comment: I agree with you, but I have "24" cal columns. It causes my query like a pyramid haha.
So, I still want to find a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Given your data model, that's likely the most elegant approach.  If your table was `name, date, value`, you could do a simple running sum.  But it seems unlikely that you'd want to unpivot the current data, do the running sum, and then pivot the data back to the end result table you have now.  If you're open to changing the format of the desired results, however, that would be more elegant.